# No or bad sound on Vivibook Pro 15 (ALC294)

Tags: sound, asus, speakers

I've got a Vivobook_ASUSLaptop X3500PHB_K3500PH and like many others, it comes with the ALC294 sound chip, resulting in bad or no sound output from the internal speakers. External speakers and headphones work just fine.

I've tried all posted solutions but I really can't get things to work. People throw around "solutions" like

```
sudo hda-verb /dev/snd/hwC0D0 0x20 0x500 0x1b
sudo hda-verb /dev/snd/hwC0D0 0x20 0x477 0x4a4b
sudo hda-verb /dev/snd/hwC0D0 0x20 0x500 0xf
sudo hda-verb /dev/snd/hwC0D0 0x20 0x477 0x74
```

but they never come with explanations of what the node, verb and parameter value are. It seems like each model of Asus needs different parameters and nobody seems to be able to explain what, why, where, etc.

Some of these commands make me get "some" noise out of the speaker, but it kind of sounds like a microphone that is being used as a speaker (low noise, bad and metallic sound), but it still definitely comes out of the internal speakers.

When this laptop was delivered, it had a Windows 11 Home on it and sound was pretty nice, so there's nothing wrong with the hardware. Now that I installed Ubuntu 22.04.03 (with all the latest updates, but not much else) I just can't get it even half working.

I think I'm still going to going to give the Ubuntu 23.04 live cd a try but otherwise I don't know how to proceed anymore. Alsa, PulseAudio and so on are already on a level above my expertise.

Answer (score 0):

Installing Ubuntu 23.04 has solved the issue mostly. The sound is usable now.
There's still a long way to go to get the potential out of these speakers. At times it sounds metallic and the volume is still a bit too low.

Just like before, headset or external speakers are working great.